# Get Elements of Certain Type within a Div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page that is dynamically generated. A rough version of the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="brotherDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="myOtherGroup" value="A" />
  <input type="radio" name="myOtherGroup" value="B" />
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="1"></input>
  <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText"></input><br />

  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="2"></input>
  <input type="text" id="myText2" name="myText2"></input><br />

  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="3"></input><br />

  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="4"></input>
</div>
<div id="sisterDiv"></div>
```

I am trying to

1. Get all of the radio buttons in `myDiv`
2. Get the index of the selected radio button in the result of #1.

Is there a way to do this type of query in jQuery? If so, how? Currently, I have

```
var rbs = $("input[name='myGroup']");
```

I feel like I'm close.

Comment: `var rbs = $("input[name='myGroup']:checked");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var rbs = $("#myDiv input[name='myGroup']:checked"),
    index = rbs.index(),
    // amongst its siblings, or:
    inputIndex = rbs.index('input[name="myGroup"]');
    // amongst other input elements of the same group
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute presence and value selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation).
  - [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
- jQuery:

  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Yes, it is now much better :) But two things: are you sure that selector `#myDiv input[name='myGroup']` instead of `#myDiv input:radio` is acceptable? Yes, there is `$("input[name='myGroup']")` in question, but #1 is _Get all of the radio buttons in myDiv_. Second thing that I have doubts with: is `index('input[name="myGroup"]')` acceptable? Yes, there are no elements with `name="myGroup"` not in `#myDiv`, but what if they will be, even though it will not be logical? Actually you use `#myDiv` in one selector, but do not use in another - it's a little strange.

Comment: I actually don't know why I fight there for completed answer instead of OP, but let's just say that I hope to see your opinion about mentioned above problems. I still can't vote up someone's answer, because they look like incompleted ones for me.

Answer (score 0):

All radio buttons in `#myDiv`:

```
var rbs = $('#myDiv :radio');
```

Checked:

```
var checkedIndex = rbs.filter(':checked').index(':radio');
```

Comment: Typo: it is `rbs`, not `rds` in second code. About `.index(':radio')` - it will count all tags before checked `<input>` (including `<br>`), which is not desired result. [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r38czhyc/1/).

Comment: I don't want to post corrected version of your code as separate answer. So will you just replace the second code with something like `var checkedIndex = rbs.index(rbs.filter(':checked'));`? [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r38czhyc/3/). It's very strange that noone has made correct answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var rbs = $('#myDiv input[type="radio"]'); // Get radio buttons
 var result = $('#myDiv input[type="radio"]:checked') // Get checked radio buttons
```

Comment: Once again: What about _Get the index of the selected radio button in the result of #1._?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to #1:

```
var radios = $('#myDiv input[type="radio"][name="myGroup"]');
```

Answer to #2:

```
var checkedRadios = radios.index( $('#myDiv input[type="radio"][name="myGroup"]:checked') );
```

Comment: Yes, finally I see first correct answer, even though I would prefer `radios.index(radios.filter(':checked'));` - avoiding duplicate code and re-search in DOM is a good idea, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  var rbs = $("#myDiv [type=radio]") // #1
  , rbschecked = null; // #2 , pending change event
    rbs.change(function(e) {
      rbschecked = rbs.index(e.target) // #2
  })
```

```js
      var rbs = $("#myDiv [type=radio]")
      , rbschecked = null;
        rbs.change(function(e) {
          rbschecked = rbs.index(e.target);
          e.target.dataset.i = rbschecked;
          console.log(rbschecked)
        })
```

```css
#myDiv input:checked:after  {
  position : relative;
  content : attr(data-i);
  left : 12px;
  top : -2px;
  color : blue;
  font-family : arial;
  font-style : italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brotherDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="myOtherGroup" value="A" />
  <input type="radio" name="myOtherGroup" value="B" />
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="1"></input>
  <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText"></input><br />

  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="2"></input>
  <input type="text" id="myText2" name="myText2"></input><br />

  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="3"></input><br />

  <input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="4"></input>
</div>
<div id="sisterDiv"></div>
```